# SSRS(Sql Server 2016) Report error when running from IIS is 'Cannot create a connection to data source 'DSTEST'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)'

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

Am getting error when am trying to access ssrs report from IIS but when am running from visual studio directly no error is occurring the error am getting like this

**An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot create a connection to data source 'DSTest'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
Cannot open database "Test" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\EDP$'.**

Please help me how to fix this.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, SSRS is trying to use the WORKGROUP\EDP$ account to access the data the report needs. You need to change that for this to work.

Open the SSRS Reporting Portal, and locate the data source for the report you are trying to run.

In the Credentials section of the data source Properties, change the *Type of credentials* to *Database user name and password*, and enter a valid user name and password of a SQL Server account that has access to the database/tables and/or stored procedure the report is using to source data.

Click the Test Connection button to ensure it all still works. Apply. Now, try running the report again.

Either that, or try giving the WORKGROUP\EDP$ access to the database object(s) the report needs, which means adding that account as a use to the database server if it isn't already. I prefer using a SQL Server login.